# About SOAP Design Pattern

Tags: soap, throughput

We provide SOAP interface to the client. The throughput of SOAP should be about 1000 requests per second, and we just have one or two clients. Now we have two options:

1. because the client may send many requests simultaneously, we need to provide many thread to process concurrent requests for these.
2. can we require clients to maintain a small number of connections, as these connections should be long connections.

If we choose option 1, poor performance because of the short connections, we need to provide more threads. And we need more resource for these concurrent threads(for example, JDBC Connection). That is bad, i think.

So, i want to choose option 2. But I do not know whether my choice easily accepted by the client. Is that a design pattern?

Comment: Option 1 should be perfectly achievable, and easier to implement than option 2. Why have you chosen not to do it?

Comment: This question is unlikely to get a useful answer in the complete abstract, which is how you have posed it. What implementation mechanisms are you working with?